# How to take edited string input in Java?

Tags: java, input

I am trying to take input in Java by calling the below function

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public static String take_string_input(){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        return in.nextLine(); 
    }

public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Enter Name");
        String str_input = take_string_input();
        System.out.println("Entry is :");
        System.out.println(str_input);
}
```

When I am writing the input , I write 'Lion' then enter 4 backspaces to remove what I wrote and then enter 'Tiger'. My expected output is 'Tiger'. However, I am getting the output as 'LionTiger'

```
Enter Name
Tiger
Entry is :
LionTiger
```

[image: Below is screenshot of Output]

Comment: When you press backspace actually clears existing text? In some consoles backspace does not work.

Comment: Yes backspace actually clears text. I have added the screenshot.

Comment: Your code ran successfully in my Eclipse integrated development environment.  I use Windows 10 and Java 14.0.2 compiled to a Java 8 standard.  How are you compiling and running your code?  What operating system and Java version are you using?

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare a String with `in.nextLine();` in the Method and return that string

```
public static String take_string_input() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String t =in.nextLine();
        return t;
    }
```